# Want to exclude folder in tar command

Tags: linux, tar

I want to exclude test4 folder from the tar command.

Following is the command using `-` but its not working

```
tar -czvf back.test.tar.gz test/ --exclude=test/test4/
```

Comment: use --exclude option before -czvf option

Comment: While many people here *can* answer this question, it isn't really a "programming" question.  Please look at the list of sites on [The StackExchange Network](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and be sure to ask your questions on "the right one".  Note that SuperUser has (for instance) [a tag for `tar`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,Removing slashes'/' will work like a charm